# Expanding an array to pass into varargs

Tags: java

Given this function signature:

```
public static void test(final String... args) {}
```

I would like to fit a string and an array of strings into the `args`:

```
test("a", new String[]{"b", "c"});
```

But it is not possible because the second argument is not expanded.

So is it possible to expand an array to fit into varargs?

If that is not possible, what is the shortest way to construct a concatenated string array given one string and a string array? E.g:

```
String a = "a";
String[] b = new String[]{"b", "c"};
String[] c = // To get: "a", "b", "c"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Guava's `ObjectArrays.concat(T, T[])`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArrays.html#concat%28T,%20T%5B%5D%29) method:

```
String a = "a";
String[] b = new String[]{"b", "c"};
String[] c = ObjectArrays.concat(a, b);
```

Notice the order of arguments. Invoking with `(b, a)` will also work, but that will append the element to the array rather than prepend (which is what you seem to want). This internally uses [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any other shorter ways but this is pretty clean to me. With plain java (*without ant libraries*)

```
String a = "a";
String[] b = new String[] { "b", "c" };
String[] c = new String[b.length + 1];
c[0]=a;
System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, 1, b.length);
```

That will work no matter what is the size of `b`

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a separate array, and put the `String` "a" first into that array, and then copy the array b[] into the array using `System.arraycopy()`, and then pass the new array to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(a);
for(String s : b) {
    sb.append(s);
}
```

And then you can convert it back to `ArrayList` or array of Strings...

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way which comes to my mind (BUT **not clean code**):

```
test((a + "," + Arrays.toString(b)).replaceAll("[\\[\\] ]", "").split(","));
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "a";
    String[] b = new String[] {"b", "c"};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
            (a + "," + Arrays.toString(b)).replaceAll("[\\[\\] ]", "").split(",")));

}
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c]
```